# Python: Play midi notes streaming to port

Tags: python, audio, midi, audio-player, waveform

I would like to play some music in realtime with Python. The `mido` library has the capacity to stream notes to a midi port on my machine:

```
import mido

msg = mido.Message('note_on', note=60)
port = mido.open_output('Port Name')
port.send(msg)
```

But I'm not sure how I can actually play / sonify the notes that are streaming to that port. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Any pointers would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please look into `LibRosa` module.

`Librosa.stream` might help in your case.
Another option is to use PyAudio to generate audio frames or capture them from audio port too (I haven't tried this) and then a callback to LibRosa for the audio analysis. This works, though frame drops would be a serious issue here, it depends on your needs and application.

When I was working on a similar project, I found this [blog](https://blog.francoismaillet.com/epic-celebration/), it's not well documented but this might give you a small start.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up! I've learned I need to install a "backend" for mido. These are installed at the system level. I'm looking into the details...